# Functional way to create a union of all keys from a Seq of Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I've a Sequence of Maps

```
 Seq[Map[String,Int]]
```

I want to create a Seq/Set that is the Union of all keys in each of the Map.

```
unionallkeys = ( "a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3" )
```

in the example below.

```
scala> val a = Map( ("a1", 1), ("a2", 2), ("a3", 3) ) 
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a1 -> 1, a2 -> 2, a3 -> 3)

scala> val b = Map( ("b1", 1), ("b2", 2), ("b3", 3) ) 
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, b3 -> 3)

scala> val c = Map( ("c1", 1), ("c2", 2), ("c3", 3) ) 
c: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(c1 -> 1, c2 -> 2, c3 -> 3)

scala> val misc = Map( ("a1", 1), ("b2", 2), ("c3", 3) )
misc: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, c3 -> 3)
                             ^

scala> val rows = List(a,b,c,misc)
rows: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(a1 -> 1, a2 -> 2, a3 -> 3), Map(b1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, b3 -> 3), Map(c1 -> 1, c2 -> 2, c3 -> 3), Map(a1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, c3 -> 3))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write this as a fairly clear one-liner:

```
scala> val keys: Set[String] = rows.flatMap(_.keySet).toSet
keys: Set[String] = Set(c3, b2, b3, c2, b1, c1, a3, a1, a2)
```

Let's break this down step by step. First of all, the `keySet` method on a map will give you a set of the map's keys. If you wanted a list of sets of keys, you could just write the following:

```
scala> val keySets: List[Set[String]] = rows.map(_.keySet)
keySets: List[Set[String]] = List(Set(a1, a2, a3), Set(b1, b2, b3), ...
```

You could then flatten the nested structure:

```
scala> val keyList: List[String] = keySets.flatten
keyList: List[String] = List(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, a1, b2, c3)
```

Note that the result has the type of the outer collection—i.e. it's a list, not a set. You can convert it to a set with `toSet`:

```
scala> val keys: Set[String] = keyList.toSet
keys: Set[String] = Set(c3, b2, b3, c2, b1, c1, a3, a1, a2)
```

And you're done. The first line above just does all of these steps at once, and combines the `map` and `flatten` calls into a single `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

[Travis solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23187234/1206998) is immutable which is better in term of design.

Let me just provide a solution using mutable Set:

```
def keysUnion[A,B](maps: Seq[Map[A,B]]): scala.collection.Set[A] = {
  val allKeys = scala.collection.mutable.Set[A]()
  maps.foreach( m => allKeys ++= m.keySet )
  allKeys
}


// test with some random input data
import scala.util.Random
val maps = (1 to 10).map( i => (1 to i).map( k => k -> k ).toMap )

keysUnion(maps)
```

I don't know if the mutable.Set is efficient. And most probably the `.toSet` of the immutable solution does the same. So for simple case it should be very similar, but it should be better if the flatten list of keys is (really) big.

*Note:* 
when using mutable collection, it's better to hide it inside method that output a trait with immutable API. This is why the solution I provided is in the form of a function which output `scala.collection.Set`.